# String manipulation in Python 3

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to Python and I've got this problem. I want to check for a specific set of letters in a bigger string and replace it with something else. So for example I have a string "oohsadfabciushdfabcuasdabcztaeabc" and I want to replace every "abc" within that string with "5". Is there a way to separate the string into pieces with a space, so that I get "oohsadf abc iushdf abc uasd abc ztae abc"? So that I can then split the string by " " and then put together a new string by just adding everything that isn't "abc" and if it is "abc" replacing it with "5". Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to go do all that trouble, when you could simply write `mystring.replace("abc", "5")`?

Comment: Unless you specifically want the results of the intermediate steps of inserting spaces and splitting the string, there's no need to add this complexity. Just replace.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `replace`:

```
"oohsadfabciushdfabcuasdabcztaeabc".replace("abc", "5")
```

Comment: Oh my, I don't know how I didn't know about this. I feel dumb, but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is simply to replace `abc` with `5`, then there's no need to use spaces at all; this is a great use case for [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

```
re.sub(r"abc", "5", your_string)
```

If you want spaces around the `5`, you can add them in the replacement text.

```
re.sub(r"abc", " 5 ", your_string)
```

Note that regular expressions are an entire sub-language in their own right. For our purposes, we only need the bare basics (an exact match), but I always put `r"` in front of regular expressions on principle, just to make intention more clear. The `r` does nothing in this *particular* case, but it will be nice to have if you use more advanced expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `replace`:

```
mystring = "oohsadfabciushdfabcuasdabcztaeabc" 
mystring.replace("abc", "5")
```

If you do want to get the chunks separated, you can use `.split()`:

```
mystring.split("abc")
['oohsadf', 'iushdf', 'uasd', 'ztae', '']
```